# how to remove first 4 rows in each sheets using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vba, excel, ssis

There is an XLSX with 4 sheets.there is a need to delete first 3 rows from all these 
shets(sheet1,sheet2,sheet3,sheet4).How to achieve this with vb.net in ssis script task
or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: so is it the first 3 or 4 rows?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what SISS is exactly, had a quick look but not really interested it working it out.

It looks like you'll just be using Office Interop in VB.net to manipulate the workbook.

You've tagged VBA too, and creating a macro to do this, either manually or using the macro recorder would be very simple assuming you'll only ever have 4 sheets and there always named the same.

If you did want to use .net instead of VBA, the code used in VBA is not too difficult to convert to work with .net/interop

Example of how to record the macro

- Start the macro recorder.
- Select Sheet1
- Select Rows 1 to 3
- Delete the Rows
- Select Sheet2
- .....
- Select Sheet3
- .....
- Select Sheet4
- ....
- Stop the macro recorder.